# Unknown error for variable getter in extension

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a variable to `UIImageView` with an extension like this

```
extension UIImageView {
    var urlSession: URLSessionDataTask? {
        get {
            if self.urlSession != nil {
                return self.urlSession
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            urlSession?.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an unknown error (in console it's just printing `(lldb)`) for the getter `if self.urlSession != nil {`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I just wanted to add a variable to `UIImageView` but i was getting error and adding getter and setter solved it but know I'm getting this error in runtime @Sweeper

Comment: You are accessing self  (urlSession)  in get block of self (urlSession), it will create infinite loop, Just pause from pause execution program button you wlll get idea

Comment: Yeah, but what does the variable _do_? Your current getter and setter is written weirdly. It is very hard to tell what should the getter and setter do. What do you want to happen when the variable is set or get?

Comment: I don't need them at all specially getter and i can do what I'm doing in setter in other place but without setter and getter i was getting error for defining variable in extension @Sweeper

Comment: so what should supposed to return in getter? @MikeAlter

Comment: @Amir_P You can't declared a stored property in an extension, so what you are trying to do isn't possible. You can subclass `UIImageView` though.

Comment: as per @Sweeper suggestion you need to create subclass  posting sample code in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `extension` does not provide functionality for store property and you have to use **SubClass** of `imageView`

However your `get` and `set` blocks also have some problem

You are accessing self (urlSession) in get block of self (urlSession), it will create infinite loop,

Please check sample code for same

```
 class MyImageView:UIImageView {

    private var dataTask:URLSessionDataTask? = nil
    var urlSession: URLSessionDataTask? {

        get {
            if dataTask != nil {
                return dataTask
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            dataTask?.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Here you need to manage `dataTask` variable as per `get` & `set` are changed `urlSession`

Answer (score 3):

Because you want to get urlSession property, and you call `get`, inside `get` you repeat this action again. You just get infinity loop.

You should use stored property, but extensions may not contain stored properties, so the solution is **Subclassing**.

Try this code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    var urlSession: URLSessionDataTask? {
        willSet {
            urlSession?.cancel()
        }
    }
}

let image = CustomImageView()
image.urlSession = URLSessionDataTask()
```

Comment: but getter needs return statement

Comment: @Amir_P, you call getter inside getter and method can not return anything.